# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when adding parameter to a javascript method in jstl

Tags: javascript, html, jstl

Im trying to invoke a javascript method in a hyperlink onClick setting a  parameter in JSTL as below :

```
<c:if test="${not test1 && test2}">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Message....
      <a onclick="executeBusinessPatch(<c:out value="${paymentId}"/>)" style="color: #a94442"><b>Configure Now.</b> 
      </a>
    </div>
</c:if>

 function executeBusinessPatch(inAppPaymentTenderId) {
  alert(inAppPaymentTenderId);
 }
```

But im getting above error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` when the hyperlink is clicked. What could be gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="executeBusinessPatch(<c:out value="${paymentId}"/>)"
```

You have to use `'` instead of `"` when using inline javascript:

```
onclick="executeBusinessPatch(<c:out value='${paymentId}'/>)"
```

Otherwise it will treat the `"` at `..ue="${pay..` as the end of your string and continue parsing `${payment` as were it the next attribute of your html element.